# Is it possible to import CSS Styles from Javascript Modules?

Tags: javascript

I want to import Google Fonts and add custom stlyes to an existing project. However I only have access to certain JS modules. No access to HTML or existing CSS files.

The only way for me to add styles is using a JS module which looks like this:

```
// styles.js
const styles = () => `
  .custom-class {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;

module.exports = styles;
```

I have tried adding Google Fonts Import or a simple CSS Import statement both between the `backticks` or in the beginning of the `styles.js` file, without success - neither works. (I've included all my tries in one code below, but when I was testing, I only used 1 line/import statement at a time.)

```
// styles.js
import "./custom.css";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

const styles = () => `
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

  .custom-class {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;

module.exports = styles;
```

Is it possible somehow to import CSS files into a JS Module in a way, that I can use the imported CSS lines in my overrides/new stlyes?

Comment: Can you add new css files?

Comment: @innocent yes, I can add new CSS files. Just not sure how to import them.

Comment: You can create a link element and attach it to the head. Use that link to add your new css files

Comment: @innocent, not a bad idea. However, I actually tried doing it and it turns out since the app is running on the server side, there is no `document` or `window` available

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the external script using JavaScript's [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API. Here's the possible code for what you want to achieve.

```js
// styles.js

async function getCSS(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  return await response.text();
}

let myCSS = await getCSS('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

const styles = () => `
  ${myCSS}
  
  .custom-class {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
`;

module.exports = styles;
```

Please note that I haven't done any error handling in the above code. Since it is a good practice to handle errors, so I would request you to do the necessary error handling. :)

**Edits:**
Using promises the above code:

```js
// styles.js

function getCSS(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.text());
}

const styles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(getCSS('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap'));
});

module.exports = styles;
```

From other file call it like this

```js
// otherFile.js

require('styles.js').then(result => {
    // do whatever you want with the
    // result. you can even add custom css here.
});
```

Comment: I got this error: `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: @Radical_Activity can you please try using `promise`?